# How to do a subquery in group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data model:

```
`title`

- id
- name

`version`

- id
- name
- title_id

`version_price`

- id
- version_id
- store
- price
```

And here is an example of the data:

```
`title`

- id=1, name=titanic
- id=2, name=avatar

`version`

- id=1, name="titanic (dubbed in spanish)", title_id=1
- id=2, name="avatar directors cut", title_id=2
- id=3, name="avatar theatrical", title_id=2

`version_price`

- id=1, version_id=1, store=itunes, price=$4.99
- id=1, version_id=1, store=google, price=$4.99
- id=1, version_id=2, store=itunes, price=$5.99
- id=1, version_id=3, store=itunes, price=$5.99
```

I want to construct a query that will give me all titles that have a version_price on iTunes but not on Google. How would I do this? Here is what I have so far:

```
select 
    title.id, title.name, group_concat(distinct store order by store)
from
    version inner join title on version.title_id=title.id inner join version_price on version_price.version_id=version.id 
group by 
    title_id
```

This gives me a group_concat which shows me what I have:

```
id  name    group_concat(distinct store order by store) 
1   Titanic Google,iTunes                               
2   Avatar  iTunes
```

But how would I construct a query to include whether the item is on Google (using a case statement or whatever's needed)

```
id  name    group_concat(distinct store order by store) on_google 
1   Titanic Google,iTunes                                true
2   Avatar  iTunes                                       false
```

It would basically be doing a `group_concat LIKE '%google%'` instead of a normal where clause.

Here's a link for a SQL fiddle of the current query I have: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52b53/1/0

Comment: `where store <> 'google'`? it's not group_concat's job to filter things for you, except for the "Distinct" stuff. filtering is done in `where` clauses.

Comment: what you expect to get? `1 | Titanic | Google,iTunes` or just `1 | Titanic | iTunes` ?

Comment: @MarcB please see updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to determine if the title is in a specified store.

```
select title.id, title.name, group_concat(distinct version_price.store order by store),
if(count(case when store = 'google' then 1 end) >= 1,'true','false') as on_google
from version 
inner join title on version.title_id=title.id 
inner join version_price on version_price.version_id=version.id
group by title.id, title.name
```

`count(case when store = 'google' then 1 end) >= 1` counts all the rows for a given title after assigning `1` to the rows which have `google` in them. (Or else they would be assigned `null` and the `count` ignores nulls.) Thereafter, the `if` checks for the `count`and classifies a title if it has atleast one `google` store on it.

Comment: very nice, this works well and this approach is much better than my current subquery approach.

Comment: would you please be able to explain in your answer the following line and how it works? `if(count(case when store = 'google' then 1 end) >= 1,'true','false') as on_google`. How is using the `if(count(...))` different than the normal `case` ?

Comment: added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the number of version prices not on google, and the number on google. (`COUNT` does not count null values.)

```
SELECT t.id, t.name
    , COUNT(DISTINCT vpNotG.id) > 0 AS onOtherThanGoogle
    , COUNT(DISTINCT vpG.id) > 0 AS onGoogle
FROM title AS t
    INNER JOIN version AS v ON t.id=v.title_id 
    LEFT JOIN version_price AS vpNotG 
       ON v.id=vpNotG.version_id
       AND vpNotG.store <> 'Google'
    LEFT JOIN version_price AS vpG 
       ON v.id=vpG.version_id 
       AND vpG.store = 'Google'
GROUP BY t.id
```

or for another solution similar to vkp's:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name
   , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN store = 'Google' THEN vp.id ELSE NULL END) AS googlePriceCount
   , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN store = 'iTunes' THEN vp.id ELSE NULL END) AS iTunesPriceCount
   , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN store <> 'Google' THEN vp.id ELSE NULL END) AS nonGooglePriceCount
FROM title AS t
   INNER JOIN version AS v ON t.id = v.title_id
   INNER JOIN version_price AS vp ON v.id = vp.version_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Note: The `ELSE NULL` can be omitted, because if no ELSE is provided it is implied; but I included for clarity.

Comment: @David542 I just edited it, I had some of the id fields reversed.

Comment: the second solution works great. The first one I'm still having some issues running the query.

Comment: @David542 I think fixed the first one now; I had omitted an `ON` and used the wrong alias in condition on the second LEFT JOIN to version_price.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8706/2

you can just:

```
SELECT 
    title.id, 
    title.name, 
    group_concat(distinct version_price.store),
    MAX(IF(version_price.store='google',1,0)) on_google
FROM version 
INNER JOIN title 
ON version.title_id=title.id 
INNER JOIN version_price 
ON version_price.version_id=version.id 
GROUP BY title_id;
```

and add `HAVING` to the query if need records to be filtered:

```
SELECT 
    title.id, 
    title.name, 
    group_concat(distinct version_price.store),
    MAX(IF(version_price.store='google',1,0)) on_google
FROM version 
INNER JOIN title 
ON version.title_id=title.id 
INNER JOIN version_price 
ON version_price.version_id=version.id 
GROUP BY title_id
HAVING on_google;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like below

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    title t
INNER JOIN
    version v ON
        v.title_id = t.id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
       *
    FROM
       version_price vp
    WHERE
       vp.store <> 'google'
 ) c ON c.version_id == v.id
```

Syntax may be just a little off as I can't test it right now, but I believe this is the spirit of what you would want.  Cross apply is also a very efficient join which is always helpful!

Comment: I've never heard of Cross Apply. Is that valid for mysql? Also, you can try it on the sqlfiddle here to test if it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e52b53/1/0

Comment: Gimme a few minutes and I'll respond!

Comment: After looking into, I didn't see any "Cross Apply" in MySQL.  Sorry about that!  I guess this solution only works in MSSQL and maybe SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the most inefficient of the above answers, but the following subquery would work, using a `%like%` condition:

```
select *, case when stores like '%google%' then 1 else 0 end on_google 
from (select title.id, title.name, group_concat(distinct store order by store) stores 
from version inner join title on version.title_id=title.id inner join version_price 
on version_price.version_id=version.id group by title_id) x

id  name    stores  on_google
1   Titanic Google,iTunes   1
2   Avatar  iTunes  0
```